# how to loop in semantic ui react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am learning react. For css I am using semantic-ui-react. I am trying to create a tab using the documentation:`https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab`. I understand how it works now I want to generate dynamic tabs according to user requirements. Suppose that I have an object like this:

```
[{name: "10jan", key: "10jan"}, 
 {name: "12jan", key: "12jan"},
 {name: "14jan", key: "14jan"}]
```

I want to generate dynamic tabs based on this. My code is this

```
const panes = [
    { dates.map((date) => (
        return (
          menuItem:{date.name},
          render(){
            <div>Test</div>
          }
        )
      ) }
    ]
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per documentation you can do the following. see the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k6utsq):

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const data = [
  { name: "10jan", key: "10jan" }, 
  { name: "12jan", key: "12jan" },
  { name: "14jan", key: "14jan" },
 ];

const panes = data.map(d => ({
  menuItem: d.name,
  render: () => <Tab.Pane> { d.key }</Tab.Pane>
}));

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Tab panes={ panes } />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
state = {
  dataArray:[{name: "10jan", key: "10jan"}, 
 {name: "12jan", key: "12jan"},
 {name: "14jan", key: "14jan"}]
}

renderItems() {
  const {dataArray} = this.state
  return dataArray.map((item,i) => <div key={i}>{item.name}</div>)
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
       {this.renderItems()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

we don't user render method again and again.
this is a way you can render dynamic views

Comment: It does not generate dynamic tabs.what i want to generate dynaminc tabs

Comment: What is the difference between generating dynamic view and dynamic tab. here `div` is a dynamic view. You only need to put your tabview HOC into this and you will get dynamic tabs too..